# How to correctly store csv to nested dictionaries

Tags: python, csv

I would like to take a csv file and store it for calling purposes later. My current function will display the values I need but not in the format I would like. I am just starting to learn about python dictionaries and need some help with this.

```
def load_dataset(filename):
filename = 'time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv'
with open(filename, 'r') as fi:
    csv_fi = csv.reader(fi)
    print(type(csv_fi))
    mydict = {}
    for line in csv_fi:
        if [line[0]] == None:
            mydict[line[1]] = line[0:]
        else:
            mydict[line[0]] = line[0:]
    print(mydict)
```

With an output of:

```
'New South Wales': ['0', '0', '0', '0', '3', '4',...]
'Northern Territory': ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',...]
```

I would like for the output to look like:

```
"Australia" : {

  "states": True,

  "state_names": ["New South Wales", "Northern Territory", "Queensland", "South Australia", "Tasmania", "Victoria", "Western Australia"]

  "New South Wales": [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, ...],

  "Northern Territory": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...],

  "Queensland": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 2, 3, ...],

  "South Australia": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, ...],

  "Tasmania": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...],

  "Victoria": [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...],

  "Western Australia": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...]

}
```

For regions without Province/State:

```
"Angola": {

  "states": False,

  "state_names": ["Angola"],

  "Angola" : [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...]

}
```

[This is a pic of the table I am using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFsxx.jpg)

Comment: Despite what Microsoft pretends, csv is not an Excel format but is plain text: Comma Separated Values. Instead of showing a picture from which we cannot copy anything, please show the initials lines of your csv file **as text**. Open the file with any text editor (notepad, notepad++, vi, etc.) and copy/paste the content in the question.

Answer (score 0):

With a setup like yours:

```
mydict = {}
with open(filename, 'r') as file_obj:
    csv_file = csv.reader(file_obj)
    for line in csv_file:
```

To makes sure that all states are added under the correct country, you could add countries and states to the dictionary by writing (inside the loop):

```
if line[0]:
    if line[0] not in my_dict:
        mydict[line[0]] = {"states": True, "state_names" = []}
    mydict[line[0]]["state_names"]append(line[1])
else:
    line[0] = line[1]
    mydict[line[0]] = {"states": False, "state_names" = [line[0]]}
```

And to then append the data for each country/state you could write as you have before:

```
mydict[line[0]][line[1]] = line[2:]
```